# All my javascript added some code at bottom

Tags: codeigniter

My website uses CodeIgniter. Today I found my website has some added code at the bottom of all the JavaScript files, including the jQuery file. The code is like this:

```
/*4fd970*/

You are blocked by day limit
/*/4fd970*/
```

My folders permission is set to 755.

- I wonder why this code is being added to my file? Has someone hacked my site?
- Is it caused by my server?

Comment: it says "You are blocked by day limit"? That sounds like some limit on internet traffic maybe.

Comment: Where are your javascript files being loaded from? If you are loading them from an external site it could be that it is a limit imposed by that server.

Comment: Ygg@ if cause from internet traffic it no reason to add code to my javascript file

Comment: Jeemusu@ it cause by server? i really don't know it before. and when it add this script?

Comment: What are the links to your javascript files? In the `<script></script>` tags what is the `src=""` set to?

Comment: I use it in the <script src="..."></script>

Comment: Please show us the <script> code, ALL of it.

Comment: Malware, check http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/

Answer (score 3):

This is some kind of a virus. Happened to me too. Only the index.php and index.html files got modified, right? I think this is a password stealer - steals your ftp passwords from filezilla or some other ftp software and then automatically modifies the index pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, someone hacked your site...though not very well. Same thing happened to me, but when I looked closer, there was also similar code added to EVERY HTML file as well (not at the end, but somewhere in the middle of the page).......

```
<!--0f2490--><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                You are blocked by day limit</script><!--/0f2490-->
```

Best I and my web host could determine, someone made a failed attempt to insert some kind of malware into the code. It was formatted in such a way (see code above) that it wasn't very apparent. If you select all (control a), it shows up a lot easier.

Some additional info from me web host;

http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/
web site: xxxxxx
status: Site infected with malware
web trust:       Not Blacklisted

Malware entry: MW:JS:ENCODED:BADINJECTED1

Description: We identified a suspicious javascript block that results from a failed attempt to inject malicious content (blackhole injection). The site was compromised, but due to an error by the attackers, the malware was not properly added.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you were hacked, and so was I.

You should first change your server access password. Someone probably managed to get his hands on it and uploaded the malware to your server.

**Remove all the infected files and upload backup versions.**

In my case my antivirus told me I had my .js and .php infected with Exploit:JS/Blacole.BW. You could also see those "4fd970" litter the code. In some cases hacker will change the code to have your user download some malware. If you only have a few scripts you can restore a backup version of all the scripts. If deleting everything is not an option, you can make a diff with the previous version and you should be able to find out what was changed.

**Check for any file that shouldn't be there.**

I also had an .htaccess file added to my server, to have the user download the Blacole malware. I replaced it with a proper one.